# Change style of RadioButton depending on property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a RadioButton that is setup dynamically as part of an ItemsControl DataTemplate.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Ratings">
  <RadioButton.Content>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" />
      <TextBlock Text=" - " />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

I have two predefined styles (`MyCheckedStyle1` and `MyUncheckedStyle2`), which work fine individually when i set the RadioButton's `Style=` property, but I haven't found a way to change the style based on it's IsChecked property.

Most methods I attempt to try give me an exception about `Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.` (such as ContentTemplate triggers)

So pseudocode

```
if IsChecked = true then 
  style = MyCheckedStyle1
else if IsChecked = false then
  style = MyUncheckedStyle1
```

I can do this with codebehind, but I am trying to avoid this if possible and put the logic in the XAML.

Comment: Apply a style to the `Parent` of radio then with a trigger change the style of radio by IsChecked property. Another way applying a style to radio itself
then with a trigger change the ControlTemplate by IsChecked property.

Comment: The styles aren't defined by me and I can't change them. Your first option sounds like it could work, can you provide an answer that explains further what you mean?

Comment: Can't you just change the style in the code behind on Checked/Unchecked events?

Comment: Yes I mentioned in my question it can be done in the code behind, wanting to do this on the view instead as @codeDom has illustrated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a style to the Parent of radio then with a trigger change the style of radio by IsChecked property.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="101" Width="264">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="MyCheckedStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="MyCheckedStyle2" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ParentStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="Ratings" >
                            <RadioButton.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </RadioButton.Content>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="RadioButton1" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="RadioButton1" Property="Style" 
                                        Value="{StaticResource MyCheckedStyle1}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="RadioButton1" Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="RadioButton1" Property="Style" 
                                        Value="{StaticResource MyCheckedStyle2}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ParentStyle}"/>
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ParentStyle}"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```